# How to make /usr/libexec/java_home honor already set JAVA_HOME in MacOS?

Tags: macos, android-studio, ssl, sudo, java-home

I do understand that /usr/libexec/java_home is used to set JAVA_HOME, but is there any which way for the reverse, can /usr/libexec/java_home ever honor an already set JAVA_HOME ?

1. No JDK is installed in the Mac. /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines is empty.
2. Android Studio is downloaded and setup in /Volumes/DataPartition/tools/Android Studio.app
3. A '.zshenv' file is created in $HOME folder with the only entry -

   export JAVA_HOME=/Volumes/DataPartition/tools/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home
4. Therefore,

`echo $JAVA_HOME`

always resolves correctly, and prints the Android Studio Embedded JDK location.

5. However,

`/usr/libexec/java_home`

is empty, since /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines folder is empty ?

6. My project code-base relies on enterprise intranet maven-artifactory repository setup with enterprise org-only SSL certs for TLS over SSH handshake, for gradle dependencies. In order for gradle to resolve the dependencies correctly in my Mac, in Android Studio, in Terminal, in CI/CD pipelines etc, these SSL certs will need to be setup in a keystore locally so gradle may pick it up automatically at run-time. Our Platform team decided JDK's embedded keystore is the most suitable file for this. However, following script to download the SSL cert files and import them into the JDK's embedded keystore always fails.

Pseudo-code ( not exact script file for security and brevity purposes ) is as follows.

```
# Download SSL cert files by duplicating this statement for each one of them.
curl url -o /tmp/file-name.crt

# Check if JAVA_HOME is valid
if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then

    # CACERTS file
    CACERTS_LOCATION=$(find -L JAVA_HOME -file cacerts)

    # Import downloaded certs to JDK's CACERTS file.
    keytool -import -keystore $CACERTS_LOCATION -file /tmp/file-name.crt
fi
```

Concerns while executing the above script are -
7. In 'sudo' mode, $JAVA_HOME isn't resolving.
8. In 'non-sudo' mode, '/tmp' doesn't get adequate permissions for curl to download files into.
9. In either case,'keytool' isn't resolving, since default is /usr/bin/keytool, which should automatically point to $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool, given JAVA_HOME is set, but since /usr/libexec/java_home isn't set, it fails.